# How to include 2 sliders which move in opposite directions in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, slider

I need to create a UI where I need 2 sliders. One moves the default way from left to right and the other from right to left.

I was able to create a slider from right to left based on this post
[How to color the slider in shiny to the right of the value instead of to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305703/how-to-color-the-slider-in-shiny-to-the-right-of-the-value-instead-of-to-the-lef)

But once I include this code the other slider also seems to move only from right to left. How can I make changes so that the 2 sliders move in opposite action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this, note that the `.js-irs-1` is the second slider, `.js-irs-0` would be first

```
library(shiny)
my_max <- 10

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head( tags$style( type = "text/css", '
      .js-irs-1 .irs-line-mid{
        background: #428bca ;
        border: 1px solid #428bca ;
      }
      .js-irs-1 .irs-line-right{
        background: #428bca ;
      }
      .js-irs-1 .irs-bar {
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #DDD -50%, #FFF 150%);
        border-top: 1px solid #CCC ;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC ;
      }
      .js-irs-1 .irs-bar-edge {
        background: inherit ;
        border: inherit ;
      }

    ')), 
    sliderInput("slider1", "Slider 1",min = 0, max = my_max, value = 2, step = 1),
    sliderInput("slider2", "Slider 2",min = 0, max = my_max, value = 8, step = 1)
    
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    observeEvent(input$slider1,{
        updateSliderInput(session, "slider2", value = my_max-input$slider1)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$slider2,{
        updateSliderInput(session, "slider1", value = my_max-input$slider2)
    })
    
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

[image]

---

To change the direction of the sliders, all you need to change is the `.js-irs-0` with 0 being the first slider, 1 the second, 2 the third and so on...

```
library(shiny)
my_max <- 10

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head( tags$style( type = "text/css", '
      .js-irs-0 .irs-line-mid{
        background: #428bca ;
        border: 1px solid #428bca ;
      }
      .js-irs-0 .irs-line-right{
        background: #428bca ;
      }
      .js-irs-0 .irs-bar {
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #DDD -50%, #FFF 150%);
        border-top: 1px solid #CCC ;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC ;
      }
      .js-irs-0 .irs-bar-edge {
        background: inherit ;
        border: inherit ;
      }

    ')), 
    sliderInput("slider1", "Slider 1",min = 0, max = my_max, value = 2, step = 1),
    sliderInput("slider2", "Slider 2",min = 0, max = my_max, value = 8, step = 1)
    
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    observeEvent(input$slider1,{
        updateSliderInput(session, "slider2", value = my_max-input$slider1)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$slider2,{
        updateSliderInput(session, "slider1", value = my_max-input$slider2)
    })
    
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

Comment: @PorkChop- Quick question. What needs to be done if I need to move this code to a separate function. Can I have uiOutput$slider1 and uiOutput$slider2 in ui.R and then create these widgets using output$slider1 and output$slider2. I need this because the min and max have to be computed.. Do let me know.

Comment: You can do that yes, but u can also utilize the `updateSliderInput` function to update it

Comment: Thanks. Got that to work.  With the code above the 1st slider moves from left to right and 2nd from right to left. What changes would be needed to make the 1st slider go from right to left and 2nd from left to right. Tried to make changes. But it did not help. Could you please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

When I run this example, the second slider doesn't have blue line to the right: it does not have blue line at all, it is grey on both sides.

[image]

My SessionInfo:

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.6.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.4    fastmap_1.1.0     ellipsis_0.3.1    magrittr_2.0.1    R6_2.5.0          promises_1.2.0.1  later_1.1.0.1    
 [8] htmltools_0.5.1.1 tools_4.0.4       Rcpp_1.0.6        digest_0.6.27     xtable_1.8-4      httpuv_1.5.5      lifecycle_1.0.0  
[15] mime_0.10         rlang_0.4.10
```